# I lost my "expand selection" option when sorting

Tags: microsoft-excel

Currently using Windows 10 Excel and One Drive. I am working from a document I created but have shared it with another user. Not sure when it happened, but when I go to sort a column, the option to "expand selection" isn't there. Help!

Answer (score 2):

With the desktop app, I have learned that the "Expand the Selection" warning will not be invoked if there in a blank column to the left of the selected column.

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue exist both on Excel online and Excel desktop app?

1. I test on Excel online, when sorting a column, there is no "Sort Warning" windows for "Expand the selection".

[image]

2. On Excel desktop app, please choose one cell of this column which your are sorting, press Ctrl + G to open "Go To" > Special > Current region > OK. Check whether the region is only this column.

As a workaround, you may try to Press Ctrl + A to choose all the region that you want to sort.

Besides, if you select **Smallest to Largest (A-Z)** or **Largest to Smallest (Z-A)**, the Sort Warning would not be displayed.

It will display the warning only if you click on the **Sort** button under Data tab.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this thread hoping to fix my same exact issue- I found out that you cannot sort if data is in a table you created. I had to copy all of the text without formatting and paste on a blank spreadsheet. Without headers & formatting- I was able to sort by name alphabetically and keep corresponding data in rows together by using the sort function.